# How to choose alignment in NASM, Linux, 32-bit

Tags: linux, assembly, alignment, nasm, 32-bit

I'm trying to write some 32-bit assembler code in NASM for Linux, the question is, how to choose the most optimal alignment for sections, what are the general guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a processor of the  x86 family with an address bus width of 32 bit. If this holds you should align your sections to addresses that are multiple of 32. You can do this by using the `.align (4)` directive which will align the next datum or instruction to a DWORD boundary.

For more extensive information on alignment you could read the "optimizing for memory access" section in the following pdf:

[optimizing assembly](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, that guide is just what I needed!